# Proper notation for a point

Tags: geometry, notation

If a point $P$ is assigned an ordered pair $(x, y)$ is it better notation to write $P(x, y)$ or since $P$ is uniquely assigned the ordered pair to write $P \equiv (x, y)$ (or even $P = (x, y)$ to cover all bases)?

Comment: You might find [this](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/notation-of-points-with-coordinates) thread useful.

Comment: $P=(x,y)$ is fine for me.

Comment: I will avoid the notation $P(x,y)$, because it can be confused as a kind of bivariable function. As other people commented I will stick to some definition as $p:=(x,y)$, avoiding the capital letter also (personal style).

Comment: I'd refer to the point as either P or as (x,y) as convenient.  I'd declare and interpret "P = (x,y)" to mean the notation P and (x,y) both refer to the same specific mathematical object.  If I want to some how express *both* the concepts that the point is a point called P and consists of the coordinates (x,y) *simultaneously*, I think I might personally use $P_{(x,y)}$ or $P_{x,y}$.  Logically, I suppose, that doesn't actually mean anything and is not well-defined, but I think its meaning is clear in context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional notation, given the axes, is to write $P$ $(x,y)$ in diagrams. Note the space between the $P$ and the $(x,y)$. The meaning is that $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates (note the plural) assigned to $P$. Over time, $(x,y)$ has become identified with a single object: a vector of these coordinates. Thus, while it is not strictly correct to say that $P$ **is** $(x,y)$, the identification doesn't matter as long as only one coordinate system is being used.

Using the notation $P(x,y)$ is rather a muddle; it seems to be implying that $P$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. Your suggestion of using another sign, such as $\equiv$, to show the correspondence between $P$ and $(x,y)$ is reasonable, but I don't think it has much currency. We are rather stuck with the often miswritten $P$ $(x,y)$ for the present, until a better convention becomes established.