# Why points are defined without =?

Tags: notation

In so many math books we find definitions like this:

> Let $A(2,-3)$ be a point...

Why the sign '$=$' is omitted for points? Where this habit comes from? Shouldn't we write 'Let $A=(2,-3)$ be a point' ?

I find the usual notation a bit awkward, if you ask me.

Comment: Well, a point isn’t equal to a pair of numbers. There is, rather, a bijection.

Comment: In more advanced math texts the notation $A(x,y)$ is not used.

Comment: Is $A$ defined as the point $(2,-3)$ in say, $\mathbb{R}^2$? I can't answer this particular question as I am not so familiar w geometry. Typically what happens though, is "conventional notation" follows from what the original authors of a few papers or textbooks decided.

Comment: I agree with Moishe and also with you that the notation is awkward. This is why I always refrained from using it in high school. (It's interesting that this awkward notation is seemingly used across many countries!)

Comment: I've never seen the notation you suggest.  Perhaps this is just an idiosyncrasy of the text you you are working from?

Comment: @XanderHenderson: Sadly, I also saw it in some US calculus books.

Comment: @Aig Depends on context.  A point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ *is* an ordered tuple of two numbers.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Agree, but based on OP’s avatar and their description ‘About me’, I’m pretty sure that the question is about the schoolbooks on *planimetry*. Btw, from where I’m from this is a standard notation and is used very widely in schoolbooks.

Comment: This notation is also familiar to me from my secondary education in the UK. I agree that it's a bit strange from the perspective of someone who has studied maths at university, but I don't think that necessarily makes it bad notation or means it needs to be changed (since that's a small sliver of the population). It's also discussed [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/5999).

Comment: I prefer to remove superfluous symbols as much as possible. Clutter distracts, brevity clarifies.

Comment: fortunately I never had seen this terrible notation. Avoid any book that use it

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2364176/473276) thread discusses this notation.

Comment: I don't understand why all the fuss  about a notation. It's well stablished that when a function is applied to an element of its domain the notation is $f(x)$, but many times one finds the notation $\sin x$ (often with trigonometric functions) and $Tu$ when $T$ is a linear transformation. Do you also jump to object of such notations? If a notation is clear I don't see why don't use it without so much trouble. I doubt somebody misunderstand the meaning of $A(2,-3)$, specially in the context of  geometry.

Comment: I can honestly say I have never seen that notation.  That said I agree with @jjagmath that it's not that confusing or misleading to me and notations are just convention.

Comment: The first results of the google image search of "point coordinates" have several uses of $A(x,y)$ and none of $A=(x,y)$, so may be the people saying that this notation is rare or unusual are not used to do a lot of Analytic Geometry.

Comment: It's not saying the point has a given value or size, just a given location.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this occasionally, too. Probably it is some (unfortunate) mixture of writing a point $A(2 | -3)$ as in elementary geometry and the later, more carefully introduced notation $A = (2, -3)$ for the positional (row) vector of a point $A$ in analytic geometry (i.e., as coordinates in some coordinate system). Since this is essentially the same thing, people then mix the notation and write it as $A(2, -3)$.

I think it isn't more than this and you should essentially read (and write) it as $A = (2, -3)$. And yes, you are right, it is a bit awkward. :-)

PS: If you do linear algebra then, one should also better write $A = (2, -3)^t$, because transforming $A$ e.g. by a transformation matrix only works if $A$ is taken as a column vector.